# How to use cookies on ajax pagination?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I found [this](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php) and this [demo](https://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-pagination/), replacing pages with Ajax without reloading. but unfortunately, when I refresh the page. Data back from the first page again. How can I make if I had chosen page 4 and refresh the page. I'm still on page 4?

I read of some articles, I have to use cookies. But I do not understand how. Then, how?

This code jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results" ).load( "fetch_pages.php");
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show();
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
            $(".loading-div").hide();
        });

    });
});
```

What like this? `document.cookie = "page=" + $(this).attr("data-page");`

**===== Update =====**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
            $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":sessionStorage.clickcount}, function(){
                $(".loading-div").hide();
            });
        } else {
            $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php");
        }
    } else {
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php");
    }
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show();
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
        sessionStorage.clickcount = page;
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":sessionStorage.clickcount}, function(){
            $(".loading-div").hide();
        });


    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you considered using localStorage?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API